# How to change permalink for listings

Tags: permalinks, directory

I am using Directorist plugin.

I want to show the address in url bar like localhost/listingname or listingname.localhost.com. But it is showing localhost/directory/listingname. I want to remove /directory/(permmalink is /%postname%/) from within the url.
Please help me to change the url bar address permalink.

Comment: what had you tried?

Comment: Tried only changing the permalink in wrodpress admin